# Is it possible to compile handlebars templates to html?

Tags: javascript, json, templates, handlebars.js, gruntjs

I would like to compile a handlebars template to insert into a static html page. I am currently using a very simple implementation of handlebars where I use AJAX to pull in the data.json and a template in the form of a script tag in my markup: `<script id="tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">`.

Ideally I would like to use Grunt to compile my template into a new html file, is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at the [assemble grunt plugin](https://github.com/assemble/assemble/). We use for a very large site and it's probably the best handlebars preprocessor I've seen. That said, I'm not sure how it handles (or if it does) the `<script type="text/x-handlerbars-template">` tags (versus partials in separate files). We use it with separate files per partial and the task is something like:

```
assemble: {
  options: {
    partials: [ "partials/**/*.hbs" ],
    data: [ "data/**/*.yml" ]
  },
  pages: {
    src: [ "views/*.hbs" ],
    dest: "build/"
  }
}
```

Obviously your setup will be different, but hopefully you get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks @jakerella, there's no reason for me not to have the templates in external files. I will try it out now.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the handlebars template output HTML... Just pass data in, and save the outputted HTML to a file.

I don't know any tools doing this process for you. But it would be very easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks @Simon, yours is a simple solution but I would like to learn something that I can reuse for other projects too